# Interpolation of date-time data to fill in missing data for data sources with different time resolution

Tags: interpolation, date-and-time

I have 2 data sources with different data acquisition rates. My first data source is a temperature measurement over time with a resolution of `1 s`. My second source is a spectrometer with `20 ms` time resolution. I would like to synchronize the output of these two different instruments.

My initial approach was to use `FromDateString` to convert everything into a `DateTime` object, and perform comparisons using `Nearest`. This was *very* slow with the amount of data that I have (~11k data points in the 1st source, and ~5k data points in the 2nd data source).

I have a solution that "works" now, but it's less than ideal. I was hoping to use `UnixTime`, but that only has `seconds` resolution instead of `milliseconds`.

Ideally I would be able to do something like this:

```
temperatureData = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]];
spectrometerData = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]];
temperatureTimes = Map[FromDateString,temperatureData[[;;,1]]];
spectrometerTimes = Map[FromDateString,spectrometerData[[;;,1]]];
startIndex = Position[temperatureTimes,Nearest[temperatureTimes,spectrometerTimes[[1]]][[1]]][[1]];
finalIndex = Position[temperatureTimes,Nearest[temperatureTimes,spectrometerTimes[[-1]]][[1]]][[1]];
interpTemperature = Interpolation[
  {
    temperatureTimes[[startIndex;;finalIndex]],
    temperatureData[[startIndex;;finalIndex,2]]
  }//Transpose
];
(* This should yield a function which takes a DateTime object as the argument and returns an interpolated temperature value, so the following should be possible *)
interpTemperature[spectrometerTimes[[1]]];
```

This approach doesn't work, but I'm wondering if there's a proper approach. There doesn't seem to be another format like `UnixTime` but with `ms` resolution. Does this need to be a custom implementation where I define something like "`ms` since `t0` of `spectrometerData`"?

Also, any guidance on cleaning up those `Position` calls would be appreciated. I know there's got to be a better way, I just haven't found it yet.

**EDIT:**
I performed the interpolation using a custom time identifier and it seems to work *OK*

```
msSincet0Spectrometer = Table[
  QuantityMagnitude[
    UnitConvert[
      spectrometerTimes[[i]]-spectrometerTimes[[1]],
      "Milliseconds"
    ]
  ]
];
msSincet0Temperature = Table[
  QuantityMagnitude[
    UnitConvert[
      temperatureTimes[[i]]-spectrometerTimes[[1]],
      "Milliseconds"
    ]
  ]
];
interpTemperature = Interpolation[
  {msSincet0Temperature,temperatureData[[startingTemperatureIndex+1;;finalTemperatureIndex+1,2]]}//Transpose
];
```

This works as I would expect, but loses the absolute timing.

**EDIT 2:**
My previous example was poor, so I'm going to provide a better one, and demonstrate that the answer in `@lericr`'s comment works.

For the temperature data and spectrometer we can make fake data like so:

```
fakeTemperatureData = Table[
  {FromDateString["6/22/2023 14:27:12.1500"]+Quantity[i,"Seconds"],Sin[i/Pi]},
  {i,1,100}
];
fakeSpectrometerData = Table[
  {FromDateString["6/22/2023 14:28:12.5000"]+Quantity[i*20,"Milliseconds"],Sin[i/Pi]+Cos[i/Pi]},
  {i,1,500}
];
DateListPlot[{fakeTemperatureData,fakeSpectrometerData},Joined->False]
```

This generates two datasets with different acquisition rates, where one is completely contained within the other.
To accomplish what I want, the slower acquisition must be converted into `TimeSeries` and then `Interpolation` can be applied:

```
interpTemperature = Interpolation[TimeSeries[fakeTemperatureData]];
```

Then, it's possible to query data points that correspond to the more rapid spectrometer data using `AbsoluteTime` (per @lericr):

```
interpTemperature[AbsoluteTime[fakeSpectrometerData[[1,1]]]];
(* output should be ~ 0.354113 *)
```

Comment: You can provide a granularity argument to `DateObject`, and one possibly granularity is "Instant". I assume you could use that to normalize across your datetime data. As for the interpolation bit, I think I'm grokking what you're trying to do, but it would be easier if you provided actual sample input data and expected results. As it stands now, you're expecting us to reverse engineer our own test data by interpreting your code.

Comment: I can add some test data. The full data is large, but I can add some test data. I've also figured out a hack using `msSincet0` and I can provide some expected results.

Comment: I think you might benefit by looking into `TimeSeries`.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, all you really need is an interpolation function for your temperature data. Using `TimeSeries` and `Interpolation` should get you that, I think. I think the whole normalizing to milliseconds is a red-herring. But maybe I'm missing something that will be clarified with test cases.

Comment: You lost me with your update.

Comment: I think you're right. `TimeSeries` does seem to work with `Interpolation`, but I'm not able to get it to evaluate when I pass it a `DateTime` Object.

Comment: Yeah, that's confusing. Wrap your date argument with `AbsoluteTime`. Although the units are seconds, I believe `AbsoluteTime` will give fractions of seconds.

Comment: I updated my question to include some generated toy data, and include an application of your solution. I also amended the title to hopefully be more descriptive of the actual problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood the question and comments, you could proceed as follows. Let's assume you have `myTempData` as a list of time-value pairs, where each time element is an actual `DateObject` expression. You can then get an interpolation function like this:

```
myTempDataInterpolation = Interpolation[TimeSeries[myTempData]]
```

To use it, you'll need to wrap inputs with `AbsoluteTime`:

```
myTempDataInterpolation[AbsoluteTime[Now]]
```